# Hide div based on URL with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to hide a div when the URL shows a certain parameter in this case: ?rpid

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            var option = 'rpid';
            var url = window.location.href;
            option = url.match(/option=(.*)/)[1];
            showDiv(option);
        });
        function showDiv(option) {
            $('.radio_element input_container').hide();
            $('#' + option).show();
        }
```

I get the following error in the Firebug console:

```
TypeError: url.match(...) is null   
option = url.match(/option=(.*)/)[1];
```

Not quite sure what's going on here, any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What does your URL look like?

Comment: Hi, I'm running it locally through IIS: http://localhost:83/briefing?rpid=222

Comment: ProTip: `window.location.search` will give you the URL's query string  (everything after and including the `?`).

Comment: Also, when `.match` doesn't find anything it returns `null` and you can't do `null[1]` (that's what the error is saying).  Your URL doesn't contain `'option='`.

Comment: if (window.location.search.indexOf('?rpid') !== false) //hide div

Comment: @user2002495: `.indexOf('?rpid') > -1`, actually.  `indexOf` returns a number, not a boolean.

Comment: @Rocket: oh my mistake, I programmed too much in php just now

Answer (score 0):

Your URL does not match the /option=/ regexp cause "option" there is means not a value of option variable but the "option" word itself.

So you should use try `url.match(new RegExp(option + "="))` or url.match(/rpid=/).

I also recommend to change the code to

```
var rpid = url.match(...);
if (rpid)
    showDiw(rpid[1]);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks that was my mistake....url.match(/rpid=/); works however it now hides the div when rpid isn't in the query string?

Answer (score 0):

Try this to check if rpid is in the querystring:

```
var vars = [], hash;
var q = document.URL.split('?')[1];
if(q != undefined){
    q = q.split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < q.length; i++){
        hash = q[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[1]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    if (vars['rpid']) {
        showDiv(vars['rpid']);
    }
}

function showDiv(option) {
    $('.radio_element input_container').hide();
    $('#' + option).show();
}
```